# Prove the identity $\cos^2 30^\circ\tan 60^\circ-1=\cot^2 60^\circ(1+\sin^2 45^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry

Here's what I did:

[image]

But I can't prove it. Can you help?

Comment: $\cos^2 30^\circ\tan 60^\circ-1=0.299,\cot^2 60^\circ(1+\sin^2 45^\circ)=.5$. Your reasoning is correct, the identity is not. Where does it come from ?

Comment: from my math book, 10th grade

Comment: I have done it in my copybook and I just wrote the result. I though that the person who WOULD DO THE CALUCATIONS would understandit is right.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I notice you changed the degree signs into `\circ`. I put the degree signs there following the advice in (this thread)[http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19678/26091]. I don't mind the symbol either way, but I wonder what your take is on the advice there?

Comment: @Théophile : I changed it to control sequences used in LaTeX; that was all I had in mind.  I will look into what is "canonical". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that either there is a typo in the book or that you copied the question down wrong. If you take out the exponent from the left-hand side, then we have:

$$\cos 30^\circ\tan 60^\circ-1 = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sqrt3 - 1 = \frac32-1 = \frac12,$$

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have begun by writing
$$
\left( \frac{\sqrt{3}}2 \right)^2\sqrt{3}-1 =\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\right)^2\left(1+\left(\frac{\sqrt2} 2\right)^2\right),
$$
which is the thing you propose to prove, and trying to deduce something from that.  If you're trying to prove the equality is *true*, then you need to deduce that from something, rather than deducing something from that.  Your proof should begin by writing "$=$" between things *known* to be equal and *end* with "$=$" between things *to be proved* to be equal.

However, if you're trying to prove the equality is *false*, then your way of beginning the argument might make sense.  But I prefer to start with routine simplifications of the left and right sides.

Let's start with the left side:
$$
\left( \frac{\sqrt{3}}2 \right)^2\sqrt{3}-1 = \frac 3 4 \sqrt 3 - 1.
$$
Now the right side:
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}3\right)^2\left(1+\left(\frac{\sqrt2} 2\right)^2\right) = \frac 3 9 \cdot\left( 1 + \frac 2 4 \right) = \frac  1 3 \left( 1 + \frac 1 2 \right) = \frac 1 2.
$$
Numerical computation would reveal that $\dfrac 1 2$ is *not* equal to $\dfrac 3 4 \sqrt 3 - 1$, but if that's too messy, lets try assuming they're equal and see where that takes us:
$$
\frac 3 4 \sqrt 3 - 1 = \frac 1 2.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $4$ clears out the fractions:
$$
3\sqrt3 - 4 = 2.
$$
Then add 4 to both sides:
$$
3\sqrt 3 = 6.
$$
Divide both sides by $3$:
$$
\sqrt 3 = 2.
$$
Square both sides:
$$
3 = 4.
$$

So we conclude that the proposed equality is false.